# Fade animation between state transitions in ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I am using ui-router in my web application. Root div code is:

```
<div ui-view="content" class="fade-in-up"></div>
```

When I go from one state to another (/orders to /feedbacks in the screenshot below), the first state doesn't hide before the new state's fade animation has finished.

[image: Screenshot]

My css is:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(15px);
}
100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-moz-transform: translateY(15px);
}
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 }
 @-o-keyframes fadeInUp {
 0% {
opacity: 0;
 -o-transform: translateY(15px);
}
100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  }
  @keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
   opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(15px);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
   transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
  .fade-in-up {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInUp .5s;
    animation: fadeInUp .5s;
  }
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: [The FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate) has an answer to this question that worked for me.  Make sure you're using ngAnimate and then check your CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just posted a [tutorial with a working demo](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/20/Angular-ngAnimate-Tutorial-with-UI-Router.aspx) showing how to do this using ngAnimate with `CSS` transitions.

There's a couple of transitions in the demo, this is the CSS snippet for fading in new views on the main element:

```
/* start 'enter' transition on main view */
main.ng-enter {
    /* transition on enter for .5s */
    transition: .5s;

    /* start with opacity 0 (invisible) */
    opacity: 0;
}

/* end 'enter' transition on main view */
main.ng-enter-active {
    /* end with opacity 1 (fade in) */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

There's only a transition on `.ng-enter` and not on `.ng-leave`, which causes the new view (that is entering) to fade in while the old view (that is leaving) disappears instantly without a transition.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the class "main" to your DIV so it looks like this:

```
<div ui-view="content" class="main"></div>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
.main.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.25s;
  opacity: 0; }
.main.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1; }
.main.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.25s;
  opacity: 1; }
.main.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

`ui-router` will fire your `ui-view` route change view out at the same time as the incoming view in. so what you get is the previous `ui-view` still visible while the next `ui-view` is rendered and if you're animating the view out then there will be that transition duration of overlap between the old view and the new. you should look into holding off on rendering the new `ui-view` until the old one is finished animating out (before animating the new one in)

i would look into the `ui-router` `$rootScope` state change events to tap into this (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).

```
## Hold off on the state change, until current (previous) state has finished animating out
$rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) ->
  console.log "state change start", arguments

$rootScope.$on '$stateChangeSuccess', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) ->
  console.log "state change success", arguments
```

also have a look it this person's example http://homerjam.github.io/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out. they have created a module that hooks into the `ui-view` and breaks apart the change into an `enter` and `leave` where you can trigger the animate in (of new view) after the animate out (of old view) http://homerjam.github.io/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out/anim-in-out.js

this person explains what is happening with the `ui-view` change duplication https://youtu.be/W89DYSthCTQ?t=345

Comment: The video link is good at explaining the source of the problem, but he does not give a solution.

Comment: agreed-- i believe the solution will vary greatly depending on the level of `ui-view` nesting being used. the "simple" solution for an app not nested beyond a single view container would be to include an animation with duration for ng-animate to detect and trigger those change events mentioned and for nested views to include a matching (or greater) animation duration on the main view since this element is where ng-animate begins to watch `transitionend` events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` classes (If you've included the 'ng-animate' module) to trigger the animations. Then you can do something like this in your CSS file:

```
[ui-view].ng-leave {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s; 
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
```

or just set a transition property with a duration on the transform and opacity properties and just set them accordingly in the `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` classes.

Comment: I tried it, but no change. I think it is not related to css animations. Maybe it is a ui-router problem.